# TCPDF - How do I extract pages form a PDF?

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, tcpdf

I read somewhere that TCPDF was capable of splitting a PDF into individual pages or images. But there's no mention of this in the documentation or an example of how to do it. Can anyone shed some light on this and if it does't recommend a PHP based one I could use to achieve this.

I'm trying to split a large PDF into high res images.

Comment: Have you tried http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php ?

Answer (score 8):

AFAIK this is not possible with pure TCPDF - you can combine it with [fpdi](http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/) (V 1.2.1 and up!) to achieve this.

Other option to do what you want (with explanations, sample source etc.):

- [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/) together with [fpdi](http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/)
- http://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::Reuse (perl-based)
- http://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::Extract (perl-based)
- http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/ (commandline-based)

Answer (score 4):

Here's an ugly little PHP script I run on the command line to 'explode' large multipage PDF files using pdftk

[click to see phpburst php script](http://snipt.org/ugBb3)

I created it about 5 years ago, and I'm sure it could be made much prettier, but it works.

pdftk is unfortunately a bit dated. If you use file encryption from a recent version of Adobe Acrobat you'll have to 'downgrade' any passwords to older levels, or pdftk won't be able to open them. The script here does not include username/password support, but basically if you edit the two lines which read

```
  $command = "pdftk " . $filePath . " cat 3-end output " . $pagesFilePath;
```

and add

```
  input_pw yourpassword
```

in front of cat, it will read most encrypted/password protected PDFs.