# Extracting pages from a PDF file using PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf, tcpdf, fpdf

I'm using php and I want to open an existing pdf file, extract (clone) a range of pages to a new one and then save the new one to disk. I know there are several classes like FPDF, TCPDF, Zend Framework etc. I would like to know which is best and, if possible, to have an example.

Comment: Since you know about various tools that exist to do this, have you spent any time with any of them?

Comment: TCPDF is good in my experience, i googled your request and found this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934960/tcpdf-how-do-i-extract-pages-form-a-pdf

Comment: @Jonathan Obviously, I don't have the luxury of time to explore all these classes.

Comment: @dimmat I didn't suggest that. Have you had the time to explore even one, or attempt to solve your problem with any of them?

Comment: @Jonathan I've already explored Zend Framework a little bit.

Comment: @dimmat Please provide that information in your question. Tell us what you've tried.

Comment: This sounds like something that, if possible, should be only a few lines of code in each tool. I find it strange that a developer don't have an hour to spare for exploring and testing different tools and making well-informed decisions. Whose job is that if not yours? I'm sorry that this is off-topic, but I think it's an important question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in example #3 here:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.pages.html#zend.pdf.pages.cloning

Open the pdf, clone the pages you want, save them into a new pdf.

Comment: Yes, I think that Zend is the most suitable for cloning pages from PDF files. Thank you Ashley!